# Let $\phi(t)$ an irreductible monic divisor of the characteristic polynomial of T, hence $(\phi(t))^p$ is the T-annihilator of a nonzero vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, irreducible-polynomials

> Let T be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space V.Let $\phi(t)$ an irreductible monic divisor of the characteristic polynomial of T, hence for some integer p, $(\phi(t))^p$ is the T-annihilator of a nonzero vector of V.

The part above is a simplified part of what I think is being used as an argument in the proof of the theorem.

I was trying to understand theorem 7.23 from Friedberg's book Linear Algebra. but the highlighted part in the image is not clear to me.I don't understand why a non-zero vector must exist.[image]

Comment: Please don't use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. See [here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: If you take a companion matrix corresponding to $\phi_i(t)^p$, then the vector that generates the corresponding $T$-cycle is a nonzero vector of $V$ that is annihilated by exactly $\phi_i(t)^p$. You know there is at least one such block/companion matrix/vector because of how $C$ is constructed.